# BottomNavigationBar Icon Not Showing

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I just created bottom navigation bar and aligned it to bottom I don't know what's the problem I am not getting icons visible when I run the program.
MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/TextcolorforWhite"
tools:context=".activities.MainMenuActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/menu_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"/>
</ScrollView>

<com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
    android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/red_border_nav_top"
    app:menu="@menu/user_nav_menu" />
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRVI4.png)

user_nav_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_Menu"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu"
    android:title="@string/menu"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_Deals"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/deals"
    android:title="@string/deals"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_TrackOrder"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/track"
    android:title="@string/track"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_Settings"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"
    android:title="@string/settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/></menu>
```

Red_border_nav_top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp">
<item
    android:bottom="-2dp"
    android:top="1dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:left="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/TextcolorforWhite"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

I searched every where in internet to find solution for this but nothing helps out for this.

Comment: Please keep your RelativeLayout height as match_parent in your MainActivity.xml

Comment: And please don't put recyclerView inside the ScrollView , it will make your recyclerView scrolling slower because RecyclerView has its own scrolling

Comment: @AbhishekSharma ok, still it didn't solve the problem

Comment: just to cross check what color your menu drawable icons have?

Comment: @prashant17 #e74c3c